# Unable to login with Windows Auth on server but can externally IIS 7

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, authentication, iis-7.5, team-foundation-server, windows-authentication

I'm running Windows Server 2008 Standard Edition with IIS 7.5.  I have TFS 2013 Update 2 installed and for whatever reason I cannot connect to my web site which requires Windows Auth while remote desktop'd onto the server, however, if I connect via a browser externally or from within Visual Studio 2013 I can connect fine.  The problem is that the build system needs to connect to TFS from the same server and therefore cannot authenticate via Windows Auth.

I tried removing/reinstalling Windows Authentication in the roles manager, that didn't make any difference.  I've tried changing the Windows Auth options, again, no difference.  I tried adding the https site to the Intranet settings in the windows control panel Internet options area - again, no change.

Why from within the server itself can I not authenticate with Windows auth but if I connect via a web browser external to the server I can?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code in the 401.1 page was Error Code 0xc000006d and when googled took me to http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896861 and adding the registry key resolved the issue.

Comment: This just solved a completely different problem - Two web services on the same IIS instance trying to windows authenticate to each other.... This key solved it!!!